# How can I change the style of biblatex to display 6 names and "et al"?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I want to get the following style for my bibliography: 
[image]

Where I get the name of a maximum of six authors and if there are more I get six plus et al.

When there are less than 6 authors (1) I have not problem using 
`\usepackage[maxbibnames=6, maxcitenames=6]{biblatex}`

However if there are more than 6 authors (2) it only displays the first one plus "et al." I have not been able to find out any solution for this.
How can I solve it?

My actual code is as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,spanish]{article}



\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=6, maxcitenames=6]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography2.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  consectetuer adipiscing elit.   Ut purus elit,\cite{1}
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.   Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.\cite{2}

\newpage
\printbibliography[title={Referencias bibliográficas}]
\end{document}
```

I get this

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When a name list hits the `max(bib|cite)names` limit, it is automatically truncated to `min(bib|cite)names`. So if you want to see up to six names in the bibliography you need to set

```
minbibnames=6, maxbibnames=6,
```

You can combine `maxbibnames=6, maxcitenames=6,` into

```
maxnames=6,
```

and if desired you can do the same for `min(bib|cite)names`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,spanish]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=numeric,
  maxnames=6, minbibnames=6,
  giveninits=true, terseinits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\DeclareDelimAlias*{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}{%
  \restorecommand\lbx@finalnamedelim
  \restorecommand\lbx@finallistdelim
}
\makeatother

\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \autocite{aksin}
vestibulum ut \autocite{companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Aksın Ö, Türkmen H, Artok L, Çetinkaya B, Ni C, Büyükgüngör O et al. “Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics of saturated Pd-N-heterocyclic carbenes in Mizoroki-Heck reactions”. En: J. Organomet. Chem. 691.13 (2006), págs. 3027-3036.//[2] Goossens M, Mittelbach F, Samarin A. The LaTeX Companion. 1. a ed.Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley, 1994. 528 págs.]